# Sql datatype for both character and integer

Tags: sql

So I just started sql. There is `int` for integers, `character` for character `string` and `varchar` for either integer or character. Is there a datatype using which I can input both the types together( e.g., A10) ? If not is there an alternative way of doing so?

Comment: Why is varchar not appropriate for `A10`?

Comment: You answered your question in your question.

Comment: You can't store `A10` in an `integer` (or even `decimal`) column. So you do not have the choice in the first place.  (Plus you should _always_ mention the DBMS you are using. "SQL" is just a query language, not a DBMS product)

Comment: Varchar and char are pretty much the same, just a length / padding difference. (Varchar is more like C char type, while char is Cobol/fortran style.) Never store numeric (float, int, decimal etc) data in char/varchar. A10 is not a numeric value, its a string value.

Answer (score 1):

You said `"varchar for either integer or character."` Note that the data can be either integer or character or alphanumerics (A10 in your example). This is why VARCHAR is in all DBMSs. It is the datatype you need to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CHAR , VARCHAR , VARCHAR 2 , NVARCHAR` as datatype for your field(in MsSQL). They all have some different properties but they all store alphanumeric values(i.e A10).

the difference between these datatypes are well explained in the below article:
http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_char_data_types